# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined? Node.js, Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, getproperty

When trying to  get the text of the 'name' element for my scraper. I try to grab it with the full Xpath and get the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined' I tried just using the regular Xpath but that said name: 'skip navigation' why  is get property coming back as undefined? it only happens when trying to get the channel title, it works when getting the profile image.

scaper.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


async function scrapeChannel(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    // const xpath_expression = '/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse[2]/div[3]/ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer/tp-yt-app-header-layout/div/tp-yt-app-header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/ytd-channel-name/div/div/yt-formatted-string';
    // await page.waitForXPath(xpath_expression);
    const [el] = await page.$x('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse[2]/div[3]/ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer/tp-yt-app-header-layout/div/tp-yt-app-header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/ytd-channel-name/div/div/yt-formatted-string');
    const text = await el.getProperty('textContent');
    const name = await text.jsonValue();

    const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="img"]');
    const src = await el2.getProperty('src');
    const avatarURL = await src.jsonValue();

    browser.close();


    console.log({name, avatarURL});

    return { name, avatarURL}
} 
}

scrapeChannel('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ')
```

index.html

```
  function newEl(type, attrs = {}) {
        const el = document.createElement(type);
        for (let attr in attrs) {
            const value = attrs[attr];
          if (attr == "innerText") el.innerText = value;
          else el.setAttribute(attr, value);
        }
        return el;
      }
```

Comment: "get property" isn't coming back as undefined.  "el" and/or "el2" are undefined!  Because you never initialized them!

Comment: where are "el" and "el2" not initialized I get output or "el2" I don't understand what you mean when you're saying it's not initialized. I also added a snippet from the index.html to the original post.

Comment: 1) Figure out which line gives the error (I'll bet the 1st line you find will be `await el.getProperty('textContent')`.  2) Step through the debugger (you *ARE* using a debugger, e.g. Chrome Developer Tools, right?), 3) STOP just before the error.  4) Look at the variable (e.g. "el").  5) Is it defined ... or null?  If not defined ... then WHY not?

Comment: Please update your post, showing the line# the error occurs on.  You can determine this from the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may have a typo in XPath. When I try your XPath in the browser console, it returns no elements. However, with this one change, it returns an element:

```js
$x('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse[1]/div[3]/ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer/tp-yt-app-header-layout/div/tp-yt-app-header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/ytd-channel-name/div/div/yt-formatted-string')
.......................................................^: 1 instead of 2
```